# Obtener campo con jpa

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jpa

Estoy trabajando con jpa y para obtener es este caso un usuario por medio del nickname utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
@Override
public User obtenerPorNick(String nickName) {
    return entityManager.find(User.class, nickName);
}
```

Eso funciona.
Tengo entendido que el `find()` es para primarykey,
lo que yo quiero es obtener un usuario pero por otro atributo por ejemplo mail que es Unique.
Que deberia usar???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso deberás crear un método en el `EJB` correspondiende .

**Ejemplo:**

```
Public usuario buscarPorMail (String correo)
{ 
String consulta ; 
Usuario usuario=null;
Try {
Consulta="from usuario u where u.correo=?";
Query query = query. CreateQuery (consulta);
Query.setParam (1,correo);
usuario=query.getSingleResult ();
}catch ()
{}
Return usuario;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sustituir el contenido de tu método por:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);

Root<User> rootUser = cq.from(User.class);
cq.where(cb.equals(rootUser.get(User_.nickName),nickName));

cq.select(rootUser);

entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList(); //en caso de ser Unique, podrias usar getSingleResult()
```

La generación automatica de metamodelos (en el ejemplo "User_") se habilita desde eclipse en :

sobre el proyecto -> Properties -> JPA -> Cannonical Metamodel -> Selecciona source folder src/main/java o el paquete correspondiente